# Not able to set environment variable in Dockerfile for Custom runtime environment in google app engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, environment-variables, dockerfile, app-engine-flexible

### I'm using below Dockerfile for setting up a custom runtime environment for app engine.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest   
RUN apt-get update -y  
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev xmlsec1

RUN apt-get install -y curl unzip
RUN curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz > /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz  
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud  
RUN tar -C /usr/local/gcloud -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz  
RUN /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh

RUN curl https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.40.zip > /tmp/google_appengine_1.9.40.zip  
RUN unzip /tmp/google_appengine_1.9.40.zip -d /usr/local/gae

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin  
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gae/google_appengine/
COPY . /app  
WORKDIR /app  
EXPOSE 80  
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  
ENTRYPOINT gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

### Issue:

The problem is that I have downloaded app engine library zip file and unziped it and added to the PATH variable but still while running the app through the specified entry point I'm getting import error. Reading about docker images in GAE I came to know that by default it runs in root profile so I don't think the issue is related to updating PATH variable of root profile and accessing it in some other profile.

### Below is the stack trace

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app  
__import__(module)
File "/app/main.py", line 6, in <module>
from com.sears.mrp.handlers.ProductRuleHandler import ProductRuleHandler  
File "/app/com/sears/mrp/handlers/ProductRuleHandler.py", line 1, in <module>
from google.appengine.ext import ndb  
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
[2016-11-28 09:10:17 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
[2016-11-28 09:10:17 +0000] [5] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2016-11-28 09:10:17 +0000] [5] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.*


If any one has faced this issue before please provide solution, I'm clueless on that to try more.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the first line in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat-multicore
```

You need a base image that supports the App Engine APIs supports 7 APIs in the standard (runtime: python27) App Engine runtime.

You are getting the import error above because the app engine APIs which are not available in the runtime specified by your Dockerfile.

Read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/customizing-the-python-runtime).

Comment: I need some c libraries to be installed which I did using "RUN apt-get install -y python-pip build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev xmlsec1" however if I use python as base image I can't do that. As it needs apt-get.

Comment: yes, you can keep all those statements, just replace `FROM ubuntu:latest` with `FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat-multicore`

Comment: Thanks, that resolves the ndb library issue, I changed the base image as you suggested but now I'm getting "BadArgumentError: app must not be empty." It looks like the webapp2 applications should not be launched using ENTRYPOINT gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app   . Any idea how to launch a webapp2 application from a flexible environment. Any document pointing to it will also help. Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Comment: You should not use gunicorn to start your app when you extend the app engine runtime. Instead, configure your app.yaml handlers, like you would if you were using the standard environment.

Comment: Below is my app.yaml file:                                                                                             runtime: custom
env: flex
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

Comment: `app.yaml` seems okay, remove this line from Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129247/discussion-between-chetan-and-atimothee).

Comment: I removed ENTRYPOINT gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app but it seems it was not able to locate app.yaml file then I added ENV  MODULE_YAML_PATH app.yaml to my dockerfile and it solved that issue but now I'm getting attribute error  at File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/vmruntime/vmconfig.py", line 63, in BuildVmAppengineEnvConfig
    escaped_appid = appid.replace(':', '_').replace('.', '_')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'